# Comparasion of two wav files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-analysis

Hi I am working on one project and I have some trouble with comparison audio files. I have read a lot of articles about this problem but I couldn't find a good one working.

In my project I need to compare two audio events like gun shot, explosion, crying, breaking of glass, ... These files have max 5sec duration but it can be different. I store these in database and there will be more examples from one audio event. Users will load his .wav file (max 5sec) into program, and program shows all files in database where is similar with the uploaded audio event. What I need is recognize which audio event is it. For example if an user uploads some explosions, program will return all files including some kind of explosion. So I am not looking for exact match. I just need find out how similar is this file with these in database. I need it in some numbers , maybe in percentage, so I can tell the files which match 90% or more.

So what is the best technique to find this kind of similarity, which way is best for my case?

Comment: Please don't cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129371/how-do-i-compare-two-wav-files-in-matlab

Comment: There are many possible approaches to this problem. You might want to take one of them, and then ask a more specific question about how it might be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something called "audio fingerprinting". This might employ DSP techniques, but in this form the question might be percieved as somewhat broad. There is no one correct algorithm of this kind, rather a bunch of good ideas that can be combined in different ways.

Comment: I have read about audio fingerprinting but its seems to me thats its find only exact match, in other words that can tell me only if the two signlas are exactly the same or not. 
Maybe corellation is a good way for me but I dont understand the result from it

Comment: I wouldn't put it like that.